# LinearLayout doesnt appear correctly after changing its height through applyTransformation

Tags: android, animation, height, android-linearlayout, gradient

I'm trying to perform a smooth transition (expand/collapse) on my `LinearLayout` through `Animation`. Here's the code that i'm using for the animation:

```
Animation anim = new Animation(){
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t){
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        layout.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(84*interpolatedTime);
        layout.requestLayout();
    }
};
```

The problem is that the expand/collapse animation works fine but the layout itself doesn't appear correctly once the animation is done. That following gray gradient block is how it looks like (instead of a textview and edittext):

[image: improper layout rendering]

Even though i'm calling `layout.requestLayout();` but still it doesnt refresh the drawing of layout at each interpolatedTime time. Is there something i'm missing here?

*P.S. The reason why i'm using **84** when setting height is because I know the rendered height of my layout and it is statically defined only during the test/debugging process.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've figured out!
The key answer is to set your view's height to `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` once the **interpolatedTime** time is equal to **1**. For example:

```
if(interpolatedTime == 1)
     layout.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
else
     layout.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(84 * interpolatedTime);
```

*Note: here 84 is the height of my view and practically it should be retrieved dynamically using `layout.getMeasuredHeight()`*